# Laravel subdomain routing different tld

Tags: laravel, dns, subdomain, laravel-8

I've got a Laravel site now I want to add a subdomain.

Example:

My site is on `example.com` now I add a subdomain:

```
Route::domain('account.example.nl')->group(function() {
    Route::get('/', function() {
        dd('yes!');
    });
});
```

Note that the tld is different (`nl`). The CNAME DNS for `account.example.nl` is pointing to the `example.com` ip address.

Why is this not working? I've tried this^, is it even possible?

Comment: If the domain is pointing to the laravel public folder, this route should work fine.

Comment: so do you want `account.example.nl.example.com` ?